# Getting error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, android

I am writing a code for a simple login app.

Code of my php script :

```
<?php 

class DbOperation {
 private $con;

 function _construct() {

    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
    echo "Hereee";
    $db=new DbConnect();
    $this->con=$db->connect();
 }

 function addUserInLogin($uname,$pass) {

     $pword = md5($pass);
     $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `login` (`uname`, `pword`) VALUES (?,?);");
     $stmt->bind_param($uname,$pword);

     if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true; 
    }  
    else false;


 }

}
?>
```

18th line refers to that `$stmt = $this->con->prepare`

Help me to get out of this problem !!

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database?

Comment: I just tried it on Postman by giving suitable parameters.,
I am getting that error

Answer (score 0):

You need two _'s

```
function __construct() { 
 require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
 echo "Hereee";
 $db=new DbConnect();
 $this->con=$db->connect();  }
```